# Is there an OpenCV version which links against GStreamer 1.0?

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I am using the GStreamer C/C++ API in a C++ program, in particular AppSrc and AppSink.
I need to pull samples from the AppSink (it works ok) and process the frames with OpenCV. But the problem is that OpenCV is linked against gstreamer0.10 (I am using Archlinux). So it does compile okay, but I get a runtime error, because gstreamer0.10 is already initialized.

So is there a "git-version" or "developer-version" which links against 0.10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems OpenCV is not ported to GStreamer 1.x yet, but other distributions are just disabling the GStreamer module of OpenCV anyway. It's not that useful, especially if you use GStreamer directly anyway.
Porting it would seem like 2 hours of work though.

Not that this necessarily helps you, but best would be to try building OpenCV with GStreamer support.

Also unrelated, please note that in gst-plugins-bad there is an OpenCV plugin that provides many filters already and also infrastructure for glueing OpenCV and GStreamer together.

Comment: What do you mean by "glueing OpenCV and GStreamer together" ? Is there some documentation that allows me to write a custom pipeline element with OpenCV ?
Because the existing OpenCV plugins don't do what I need, this is why I need to use custom OpenCV calls.

Comment: If you look here: http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-bad/tree/ext/opencv

you will see code that converts between CVImages to GstBuffers and back, and some other glue code that allows you to easier work with OpenCV inside GStreamer